# How to pass query string to a post request using mulesoft

Tags: http-post, mule, anypoint-studio

I am new to Mulesoft and am trying to send some (four) query parameters. When testing using SOAP UI
[A screen shot of what I tested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0zHc.png)

I replicated this in mulesoft using the following xml configuration

```
<flow name="boxintegrationFlow1">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration1" path="*" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <logger message="Message: #[message.inboundProperties] Code: #[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.code]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" doc:name="Property"/>
    <set-variable variableName="QueryParameters" value="{'grant_type':'authorization_code', 'code':''#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.code]','client_id':'abc','client_secret':'xyz'}" doc:name="Variable" mimeType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
    <logger message="#[flowVars.QueryParameters]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <set-payload value="#[flowVars.QueryParameters]" doc:name="PostQueryParameters"/>
    <http:request config-ref="getToken" path="/oauth2/token" method="POST" sendBodyMode="ALWAYS" doc:name="HTTP">
        <http:request-builder>
            <http:query-param paramName="grant_type" value="authorization_code"/>
            <http:query-param paramName="code" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.code]"/>
            <http:query-param paramName="client_id" value="xyz"/>
            <http:query-param paramName="client_secret" value="abc"/>
        </http:request-builder>
        <http:success-status-code-validator values="400"/>
    </http:request>
    <logger message="Message: #[message.outboundProperties] " level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

On doing this am getting an error "{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing"}"

I understand that we have pass it as a query string, but am not able to figure out how do I do it.

Any pointers are appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The error appears that you are using the [Mule OAuth provider](https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/building-an-external-oauth-2.0-provider-application) or something like it.  If that is the case, your issue is not that you are adding grant_type incorrectly as a query parameter, it is that you are sending the client ID and secret as parameters.

You need to send your client id and secret as a Basic Authentication header.  The header should have the form `Authorization: Basic NmJlXXXXXXXXXXc0NDZlYmFhNTgzMWQ0NDRhZmNjMmE6MzJkZTE1ZDZZZZZZZZZZZkFEOEJEQUU5QkNG`.

Example using curl to the Mule OAuth Provider running locally (using resource username/password grant type):

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Authorization: Basic NmJlXXXXXXXXXXc0NDZlYmFhNTgzMWQ0NDRhZmNjMmE6MzJkZTE1ZDZZZZZZZZZZZkFEOEJEQUU5QkNGMjc4RDYK" -d "grant_type=password&username=max&password=mule" "https://localhost:10101/external/access_token" -k
```

Comment: its working fine when  am testing it. There am sending it as query parameters.

Comment: You're also setting parameters in both query string and post body.  You should only do it in one place.  I know the mule OAuth provider will give you an error if you put it both places.  Remove the body and just use the query string and vice versa.  That is likely your issue.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.. as suggested i did try removing them at one place.

Comment: I got the solution when I passed the values through a payload as a parameters but not key value pair...